# EmberJS: How to handle actions from the View not the Route / Controller

Tags: view, ember.js, ember-router

Today I have come to a shocking discovery: actions referenced on a view are handled by their route, not by the view which referenced it. Ex:

```
<a href="#" {{action edit}}>Edit this</a>
```

The `edit` action must be defined in the Route, not in the View. When I was not using a Router before the View was the one responsible for handling such events and I was really happy about it.

Can anyone please:

1. explain to me why the Route must handle the event, and what are the benefits of this
2. tell me how can I give control back to the View in matters of handling such actions/events?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Set the target as view

```
<a href="#" {{action edit target="view"}}>Edit this</a>
```

If your action is in controller then use

```
<a href="#" {{action edit}}>Edit this</a>
```

Default target refers to the view's controller

I'd suggest you to go through this **Reference:** [Ember Action Helper](http://emberjs.com/guides/templates/actions/)

I'd like to mention some key points as per the above reference

In a typical Ember.Router-backed Application where views are managed through use of the {{outlet}} helper, actions will be forwarded to the current controller.

If the action is not defined in the controller, then the current route is targeted.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your reply, it worked indeed!!! Is there any reason why the router takes control by default? is this supposed to be a good practice?

Comment: I really don;t know the reason for router being the default, see the link in the updated answer

Comment: Thanks again, I'll check everything throughly and try to find the best approach.

Comment: as a side note, if the action is only UI specific then it makes sense to have this action only in the VIEW and not the controller or the router, although it will eventually look there for the 'action' if it

Comment: as a side note, if the action is only UI specific, then should not it be handled only in the view rather than have the default target as controller ?